# preg_match exact start and end with 3 digits number as exact match is not working?

Tags: php, function, if-statement, numbers, preg-match

Very basic ::

Any 3 digits number that as exact match.

Looks like it's true but it return false.

Why this is not TRUE ?

```
<?php

if ( preg_match( '#\^d{3}$#', '123' ) ) {
    echo ':)';
    } else {
    echo ':(';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression:

```
\^d{3}$
```

**What it means:**

- `\^` - matches the character `^` literally
- `d{3}` - matches the character `d` literally (exactly 3 times)
- `$` -  assert position at the end of the string

**Visualization:**

[image: Visualization]

In simple English: it matches a string that looks like `"^ddd"`.

**What you probably need:**

```
\d{3}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check any 3 digits you use this:

```
<?php
    if ( preg_match( '/^\d{3}$/', '123' ) ) {
      echo ':)';
    } else {
      echo ':(';
    }
?>
```

This return the happy face.